# JQuery-bPopup Remove the old page from the popup and load a new page in same

Tags: javascript, jquery, bpopup

In JQuery bPopup, how can i remove the old page from the popup and load a new page in same popup without closing it?

I have tried following 3 things, but still no success:

- Applied anchor tag in child page, but it opens the new page in parent page
- Applied $('.popup_content').bPopup({...}); in child page, it opens new page along with the previous page, both page are there in two rows.
- Put 4 divs for popup in parent page, and called bPopup() for seperate popup divs in child pages. It works well, but keeps open the overlay of the old page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function fnPopupClose1() {

    var popup = $('.popup1').bPopup();
    popup.dispose = true;
    popup.close();
}
```